# How to set a label in a cell of tableview by code?

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, swift3

If I just want to set a label by code, I should write for example like this,

```
let label = UILabel()
label.frame = CGRect(x:10, y:   10, width:160, height:30)
label.text = "Test"
self.view.addSubview(label)
```

but if I want to set a label in a cell of tableView, how can I set it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

UITableviewCell subclass has textlabel property which you can use

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
   let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
   cell.textLabel?.text = "My Text"
   return cell
}
```

or alternatively you can use custom cell for more control

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell
    let label = UILabel()
    label.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 160, height: 30)
    label.text = "Test"
    cell.contentView.addSubview(label)
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Since you're using a reusable cell here, this is a very poor solution; your code will add a UILabel for each time a cell is dequeued.  A better solution is to use a custom UITableViewCell with a UILabel, whether in the storyboard, a xib file, or set up programmatically _once_.

Comment: my bad, edited the code with default tableview subclass

Comment: Your custom cell implementation still has the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should create you a custom class for you cell as such. This adds a label to a cell and uses anchoring system to set constraints on the label to fill the entire cell.

```
class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {
let label: UILabel = {
 let n = UILabel()
     n.textColor = UIColor.darkGray
     n.textAlignment = .center
     n.text = "Testing 123"
     n.font = UIFont(name: "Montserrat", size: 30)
 return n
}()

 override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

    addSubview(label)

   label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
   label.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftAnchor).isActive = true
   label.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightAnchor).isActive = true
   label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor).isActive = true
   label.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor).isActive = true
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
}
```

For the ViewController that uses this custom cell, you have to add the below cell registration like such, unless you're using storyboards/interface builder.

```
class ControllerUsesCell: UITableViewController {
  let defaultCellId = "cellId"

  override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView?.register(CustomCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: defaultCellId)
   }

  }
```